# covariance matrix for latent variables loadings (gllvm package in r)

Tags: glm

I am exploring the glm models with latent variables and would like to compute the covariance matrix for the latent variables loadings of a gllvm fitted object. I have used the vcov function from the same package as well as the getResidualCov but the vcov function returns a non symmetric matrix (I fail to understand why) and the getResidualCov does not seem to compute the asymptotic covariance matrix that can be computed by inverting the derivative of the likelihood wrt loadings transposed times derivative wrt loadings. Any help? Thank you in advance!

get a symmetric positive definite matrix for the latent variables loadings, I have tried vcov and getResidualCov and I was expecting to get
[formula here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SwcD9.png) , where $\alpha$ are the latent variables loadings.

Comment: What sort of data did you apply gllvm on?

Answer (score 0):

Apologies for the slow answer, I (or the other gllvm devs as far as I know) do not regularly check stackoverflow (posting an issue on the package github is usually quicker). A reproducible example would be helpful to further explore the issue you are having.

The vcov function should produce a square symmetric matrix. However, especially for poor fitting complex models, the covariance matrix can be asymmetric (note that I have not personally encountered it in the gllvm R-package), which usually has to do with inaccuracy in the involved calculations. My suggestion (without having seen your code, data, model and so forth) would be to explore the model fit a bit further.

You can try different (sets) of starting values, potentially different optimizers, and different numbers of latent variables and such, to try and diagnose convergence issues. You should have a look at the gradient of the model (there is an option in gllvm that does this for you), to make sure all values are close to zero.

Without more information, I am unfortunately unable to go further into detail.